# Does SmartAssemby support multiple-assembly app?

Tags: .net, assemblies, smartassembly

My console application contains one exe and 10 dlls. I want to and can only obfuscate five of the dlls. The rest are shared dlls and contain common code so they cannot be obfuscated. With the current design the obfuscated assemblies also cannot be merged or the app will break.

Can SmartAssembly be used for my situation? It only lets me pick one assembly to obfuscate. It seems I have to create a project for each dlls I want to obfuscated. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to leave the DLLs as separate files then they will need separate projects.  If they are shared you will need to do this.

The recommendation is to merge everything you can (those assemblies which aren't shared) into your .exe's project.